# MVC 5 Routing with Model Data

Tags: asp.net-mvc, model, asp.net-mvc-routing

I have a html form which post back model data to controller.

After user enters info , the form is submitted to Controller : U , Action : Arama

On submit I want to create a custom URL containing user entered model data.

My Model:

```
string Nereden
string Nereye
string NeredenKod
string NereyeKod
```

What I want to do is use just 2 of this data in URL eventhough I need the complete model in the  controller.

What I mean , I want this form to submit to this url(The rest of the data will not be on the url) :

localhost:34534/U/Arama/{NeredenKod}/{NereyeKod}

Answer (score 0):

Assuming your action is like this:

```
public ActionResult SomeActionName(SomeModel modelName){
    //Code here
}
```

You can define the route like this:

```
routes.MapRoute(
   name: "SomeRouteName",
   url: "StaticPath/{modelName.NeredenKod}/{modelName.NereyeKod}",
   defaults: new { controller = "SomeControllerName", 
                   action = "SomeActionName" }
  );
```

Make sure you put this above the default route.

Comment: It doesnt work , i put it above default route. Can it be becouse the model is empty when cshtml is first rendered
 routes.MapRoute(
              name: "Arama",
              url: "ulasim/{gelen.NeredenKod}",
              defaults: new { controller = "U", action = "Arama"}
          );

Comment: @BurakGazi have you tried to put break point on the controller in debug and see if the model object is `null`?